# what is '?' in service --status-all

Tags: services

by this command service --status-all . I can find all services status. in every line there is + or - or ?. Easy to guess + and - which **may be** refer to running service and not running (**I'm not sure**).But do not know this ? symbol meaning before services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question mark indicates that `service` was not able to determine the status of the running service since it did not find the status line in the related script in `/etc/init.d`

The service command has a snippet as follows:

```
if ! grep -qs "\Wstatus)" "$SERVICE"; then
    #printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[?]" "$SERVICE:" "unknown" 1>&2
    echo " [ ? ]  $SERVICE" 1>&2
    continue
```

which indicates that it will mark the status of a service as `[?]` if it does not find a line which has the word `status` after any non-word character in the related service's file in `/etc/init.d`.

For example, I have the following cases to consider for this specific example

- For `[+] acpid`, if I browse the file `/etc/init.d/acpid` I get the following line:

  ```
  status)
  status_of_proc "$ACPID" acpid
  ```

which I presume is what `service` is looking for.

- For `[?] apport`, I don't find a line with the word `status` preceded by a non-word character which `service` was looking for. Thus, it prepends a `[?]` before the service name when you do a `sudo service --status-all`.

---

See also: [An exactly similar question on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/446334/what-does-a-question-mark-mean-when-listing-all-services).